# Order of a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm struggling to find the order of a cyclic group.

The definition I have is: the order of a group is the number of elements in the group. However, when looking at examples, I get confused.

eg. (134)(25) has order 6. (1254) has order 4. (15)(34) has order 2.

Can anybody explain the definition of order and/or these answers please?

Comment: Note that $S_5$ has order 120, and is NOT cyclic.  But  there are many **cyclic subgroups** of $S_5$.  E.g., the element $\alpha=(134)(25)$ is an element of order 6 in $S_5$ , but $\alpha$ also generates the cyclic subgroup $\langle (134)(25)\rangle = \{id, \alpha, \alpha^2, \alpha^3, \alpha^4, \alpha^5\}$, whereas $(15)(34)$ generates the cyclic subgroup of order two: $\{id, (15)(34)\}$.  Remember that all and only those groups which are generated by a *single* element are cyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of a group $G$ is indeed the number of elements in it. The order of a *subgroup $H$ generated by $(12)$* in the symmetric group $G=S_3$, say, is two, because we have $H=\{(1), (12)\}$, with $(12)^2=(1)$. Similarly the subgroup generated by $(15)(34)$ in $S_5$ has only two elements. The cyclic subgroup generated by $(134)(25)$ has order $lcm(2,3)=6$, since the order of $(134)$ is $3$, and the order of $(25)$ is $2$, and $gcd(2,3)=1$, and the two cycles commute. Note that $S_5$ is not cyclic, we need at least two generators, e.g. $(12345)$ and $(12)$.

Comment: I'll delete my comment...no longer applicable! :-)

Answer (score 2):

These are the orders of the *elements*, i.e. the orders of the cyclic subgroups they generate.
Now these permutations all belong to, say, the symmetric group $S_5$, which has order $5!=120$. Note the above-mentioned orders of specific elements are divisors of $120$, in accordance with *Lagrange's theorem*.